# react native axios android headers not sent

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i have issues trying to get a simple axios.post and axios.get with a headers, the code is below, it works on ios without problem, but on android i have problems with send the headers across to the server, basically the headers get missed for some reason on android, any help would be great

thanks advance

here's the code i used that works on ios perfectly

```
let { data } = await axios.post(url,
        qs.stringify({
            productid: value
        }),
        { headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'xxxxxx',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        }
    }
    );
```

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362) on axios. Did you checked/tried the solutions there? Might not be the same problem but I suggest you to give the solutions a go.

Comment: that's pretty much what that code is, not sure why, it goes on ios, just android having this problem

Comment: i have also try it on fetch but still same error, so i just wondering is it some setting for android i am not doing right